# Converting Moore to Mealy When first Node has Output

Tags: finite-automata

This is a homework question, which I am able to do, except my teacher failed to mention what to do when the very first node has a 1 output. I've looked through online examples, and I'm sure this has a very simple answer, but I cannot figure out what the convention would be.

On the left, we have a Moore Machine. It's first node outputs 1. Ok, no problem.
But when I convert this to a Mealy, the only time q1 outputs 1, is when being traversed from q2.

[image: Moore to Mealy]

But if it's the first node, it should be outputting when the whole thing begins (on lambda) AND when being traversed from q2.

I had two theories, one-- I make a new beginning node, or, I actually put λ/1 on the entry arrow/line (which I have not seen done in any example). But I'd rather not guess my way through this otherwise simple operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question like a silly person:

Ok, I learned what I was missing. A Mealy Machine cannot handle a lambda as I thought it could. As a result, my question has no real answer. Things do NOT output at the first node. Only the first traversal after the first node has any real meaning.